# How to install OpenJDK 8 on 15.10?

Tags: software-installation, java, 15.10, openjdk

Is it as simple as

```
sudo apt-get install openjd-8-jdk
```

I already have `openjdk-7` installed, will the above command just overwrite it?

Will the latest version be used, despite having multiple versions installed?

Or do I have to remove `openjdk-7`?

Comment: You can have both installed.

Comment: But you'll have to choose your default I believe.

Comment: @Zacharee1 That is correct.

Comment: @Pilot6 Do you want to answer, or can I?

Comment: Please do answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait :)

Comment: The short answer is that you just install that package and set a default java using `update-alternatives`. You can use either one installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 And I'll get regular updates for openjdk-8?

Comment: Yes, why not? It is a regular package.

Comment: @Pilot6 I only thought that because it says it's not "supported by the distribution" when installing it from synaptic

Comment: I saw that it used to be updated. But you can always install it from a PPA, if it does not.

Comment: @Pilot6 I answered my own question if someone else has the same. It was that simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's that simple, just install

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

the latest version will be used, even if you have `openjdk-7-jdk` or any other.

I also installed `openjdk-8-doc`, `openjdk-8-jre`, `openjdk-8-jre-headless`, because they were installed for `openjdk-7`.